# How to deploy WAR files on different Deployment slots within a single App Service on Azure portal without dividing the traffic

Tags: azure-web-app-service

On Azure Cloud Portal I have one App Service Plan and under that I have one App service in which I have created some Deployment Slots, you can refer the below screen shot.

I have provided traffic % as per the requirement, now what happening is when I am triggering a request to my main App Service which is "**wa-45210-jira-stg1-win**" then it is routing through properly but when others are trying to trigger the request to same App service then it is getting redirected to other deployment slots like "**wa-45210-jira-stg1-win-test**". Please refer the screen shot below

Here the expectation are it should redirected to the desired app service for which the request has been triggered so that I can have dedicated deployment slots for particular environment.

I think traffic is getting divided because of the traffic % defined. If one app service is occupied then automatically the request will get redirected to other deployment slot which is not expected.

Can anyone suggest me What should I do in order to achieve this?
My goal is to create some deployment slots or something like that in one single app service so that I can manage Dev, Test & Stage environment related stuff in one App service and therefore I can save the cost.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone suggest me What should I do in order to achieve this? My
> goal is to create some deployment slots or something like that in one
> single app service so that I can manage Dev, Test & Stage environment
> related stuff in one App service and therefore I can save the cost.

**Yes**, we can achieve the above requirement . To make sure that you have selected the correct target deployment slot which need to be trigger.

For example:-

[image]

Also make sure that ,

> ***production is your target slot and that all settings in the source slot are setup exactly as you want them in production before swapping
> an app from a deployment slot to production.***

For complete configuration please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION|Set up staging environments in Azure App Service***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots)

For more information please refer this [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/110805/timertriggered-azure-webjob-in-different-deploymen.html) as suggested by @*ajkuma-MSFT*.

Comment: The configuration mentioned above is the exact configuration I have still not working. I have created 2 slots in one App Service. The main App service is ABC, and under this main Service I have created 2 slots which are : XYZ, PQR. Now my goal is to make these a dedicated slot for specific environment. If I want to trigger a request for staging then a request should go for Staging instance only. But what happening is if there is more load on main app then the request is getting redirected to other deployment slot which is not expected. The request should go to the specified slot only.